# Backbone template not rendering in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

I have an application that uses Backbone.js to render views and insert content from mustache templates. It works fine in all browsers except IE8 and lower.

On top of my Backbone view I have this:

```
template: $('#leg-template')
```

And on the bottom the following:

```
render: function () {
var order =  this.model.get('order');   

console.log(this.template.html());

this.$el.html(Mustache.to_html(this.template.html(), { 
leg_number: order
}));
```

The weird thing is that IE8 Console is not throwing any error and it's actually logging the HTML that corresponds to my template, but even if I try this:

```
$('body').html(this.template.html());
```

.. the body's content will still be empty. However the following works:

```
$('body').html('test');
```

Please help! Thanks!

Here's the leg template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="leg-template">
<div id="leg_{{ leg_number }}" class="row-fluid leg">

<div class="span1">
  <p class="reservFlightLabel">Flight {{ leg_number }}</p>
</div><!--/.span-->

<div class="span2">
  <label class="mobile-only">Origine</label>
  <input type="text" name="from" class="reserv-input" maxlength="200" />
</div><!--/.span-->

<div class="span1">
  <div class="white-arrow"></div>
</div><!--/.span-->

<div class="span2">
  <label class="mobile-only">Destination</label>
  <input type="text" name="to" class="reserv-input" maxlength="200" />
</div><!--/.span-->

<div class="span2">
  <label class="mobile-only">Date de d&#233;part</label>
  <input type="text" name="date" class="reserv-input datepicker" maxlength="200" readonly="readonly" />
</div><!--/.span-->

<div class="span2">
  <label class="mobile-only">Heure de d&#233;part *</label>
  <input type="text" name="time" class="reserv-input" maxlength="5" value="00:00" />
</div><!--/.span-->

<div class="span2">
  <label class="mobile-only">Nom. de passagers</label>
  <input type="text" name="pax" class="reserv-input" maxlength="2" value="1" />
</div><!--/.span-->

</div><!--/.leg-->

</div><!--/.row-fluid (.legs-wrap)-->       
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure the HTML you're adding is valid (all tags match, etc.) Otherwise, IE may not replace your existing HTML.

Comment: I have updated the post and added the #leg-template. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `</div>` tag; try it without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no opening `<div>` for this closing line `</div><!--/.row-fluid (.legs-wrap)-->`

```
<script type="text/template" id="leg-template">

<div id="leg_{{ leg_number }}" class="row-fluid leg">

   ...

</div><!--/.leg-->

</div><!--/.row-fluid (.legs-wrap)-->       

</script>
```